# twitter oath authentication android

Tags: android

i am developing app.its having post message on facebook and twitter.i searched on net and got many example but i confused with twitter.

if i am using oath authentication how should i provide login screens for clients.many example

what i found just they are using consumer and secret key where i need to pass uname,pword

can you pl suggest me its very urgent to me

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter using oAuth at present, so whatever api's you will get, they will open the official twitter login page in webview, so you cannot use your own login page for that, twitter does not want's that........
Hope it help's you
Good luck.......

Comment: then how i provide login page for users.u mean that it works only who register app with there login name on twitter developer network

Comment: Well if you have to post on someone wall, then you have to register your app on twitter or facebook, so it will be actually your application that will be posting on user's wall or tweet, so you will be using the key and secret key, because twitter and facebook both use Oauth nowadays, so you cannot make a user enter his credentials at your end, and then use it, both twitter and facebook will be doing the same at there end ....

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using a `WebView` (to hold the login UI which comes from twitter.com) and Signpost for the OAuth authentication. [There's a good example here](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/wiki/TwitterAndSignpost).

However, this turned out to be a less than brilliant mobile user experience - WebView login screens just suck - so I switched to using [XAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) instead of OAuth, which you have to apply to Twitter for. The benefit of doing that is that you can have your own custom login UI, which isn't web-based. Unfortunately Signpost doesn't yet support XAuth so I also changed to using a stripped-down version of [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using Singpost and Android's HttpURLConnection to obtain access token based on username and password you can have a look at my post. I was referring to Twitter XAuth so that's should be what you looking for. It works for me.

http://3citydev.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-obtain-xauth-access-token-using.html